How to setup sns notification for cloudwatch alarm using CDK for AWS Glue job
I have below code for setting up alarm for AWS glue job using CDK:
import { aws_cloudwatch as cloudwatch, aws_events as events } from 'aws-cdk-lib';

// jobName. This is our AWS Glue script to monitor
const jobFailedRule = new Rule(scope, '{DVRD replication} JobFailureRule', {
  eventPattern: {
    source: ['aws.glue'],
    detailType: ['Glue Job State Change'],
    detail: {
      state: ['FAILED', 'TIMEOUT', 'ERROR'],
      jobName: [DVRD replication],
    },
  },
})

//cloudwatch metric
const numFailedJobsMetric = new cloudwatch.Metric({
  namespace: 'AWS/Events',
  metricName: 'TriggeredRules',
  statistic: 'Sum',
  dimensionsMap: {
   RuleName: jobFailedRule.ruleName,
  },
})

//cloudwatch alarm
const numFailedJobsAlarm = new cloudwatch.Alarm(scope, '{DVRD replication} numFailedJobsAlarm', {
  metric: numFailedJobsMetric,
  threshold: 1,
  evaluationPeriods: 1,
});

Now i want to setup SNS email notification for this alarm but not sure how to do it.

Create an SNS Topic, then add it as an alarm action to the cloudwatch alarm.  Add a subscription to the topic for your email address.  confirm subscription email.

do you have any example?

example here : https://medium.com/@ureniucbogdan/unleash-the-power-of-alerts-keeping-your-finger-on-the-pulse-of-aws-glue-scripts-72640f389be7

the problem is i dont know how to use SnsAction and assigned this with alarm..
